# How to find all subsets of a integer list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I wrote the below code to find the subsets of 2 integers from the list S.

```
import itertools

S = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

subsets = itertools.combinations(S, 2)
print subsets
```

I am expecting the below result:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], ... [4, 6]]
```

I got an error from the above code as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 5, in <module>
    subsets = itertools.combinations(S, 2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'combinations'
```

Why I am not able to import combinations()?

Comment: Which version of python you use?

Answer (score 3):

From you problem description it seems that you are using Python 2.5 or lower. As [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is only available since Python 2.6 you have to upgrade to a newer version, to make use of it.

You can use `python --version` to find out which version you are currently using.